# drm/i915 GPU Hang in Artful Advark 17.10

Tags: intel, 17.10, i915, drm

I have installed fresh **Ubuntu Mate 17.10** - *Artful Advark*.

This is my Intel configuration file:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "TearFree"    "true"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option      "DRI"         "3"
EndSection
```

I have installed latest available drivers using [Intel Graphics Update Tools for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6)

Because tool wasn't able to run on 17.10 I temporary changed `/etc/lsb-release` to corespond 17.04 Zesty Zapus and then I successfully installed drivers using tool.

After all this trouble I often have issues. My screen randomly goes black for 10 seconds because of GPU HANG. Also sometimes elements flicker in programs which use HW acceleration (mostly chrome, disabling hardware acceleration is not an option because chrome works terrible)

Here is [crash dump](https://pastebin.com/raw/B1QW7bR0)

**VGA adapter info:**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
```

**Dmesg:**

```
[ 1964.877703] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 4:0:0x54f4e8fb, in Xorg [874], reason: Hang on rcs0, action: reset
[ 1964.877707] [drm] GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
[ 1964.877708] [drm] Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
[ 1964.877709] [drm] drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
[ 1964.877710] [drm] The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it.
[ 1964.877711] [drm] GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error
[ 1964.919361] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 1972.939781] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2004.879875] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2258.924142] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2376.394596] perf: interrupt took too long (7689 > 7688), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 26000
[ 2417.923699] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2708.941780] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2738.869020] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2760.862012] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2770.846041] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 2780.862186] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
```

Comment: " Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel"  so do that... we can't help you ;)

Comment: I saw that, there is already an BUG report, a few of them actually. I even found bug report from 2016 (so still isn't fixed, but i didn't have problems on 17.04).

If someone with more knowledge than me could look at crash dump maybe it's something easy to fix.

Comment: I filled another bug report if it's of any help
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got similar trouble for 3 months ! (I need to use my win***z to check HW failure. No problem with my M$  spare wheel

But after many, many search on the web

I find it's two accel mode (at least) for this graphic card
sna or uxa
So, first of all, I need to (re)install the intel  driver

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

and create/modify the

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

with these options

`Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
    #Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
  EndSection`

You can find more info about intel graphics card options at
[wiki gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel)

You need to reboot and try

Mike_X

Comment: So which one are you using?
I'm using sna

If I switch to Uxa, that solves the GPU hang?
Cuz I'm still experiencing this. Even though intel staff on free desktop said they "fixed" they have no clue. obviously. I keep updating kernel and hoping for miracles xD

Comment: I switched to UXA and I kept the DRi 3
I will see if the bug pops again. But performance is worse. I would rather restart lightdm every 20 minutes than suffer this performance loss.

Comment: thanks you saved my life